# Javascript Tab - Active Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I am using the following js which works great for hiding and showing content when one of 5 tabs is clicked. Works great but my question is, how could i adjust the code so that when a tab's content is currently being displayed, the tab has an active class. The hover class works well and so does everything else besides the active class. Any help is hugely appreciated:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#infotab').click(function() {
        $(document).find('.tabcontent').hide();
        $('.infotabcontent').show();
        $(document).find('.top-nav2-menu li').removeClass('tabactive');
        $('#infotab').addClass('tabactive');
        $('#reviewtab').removeClass('tabactivelast');
    });
    $('#findingtab').click(function() {
        $(document).find('.tabcontent').hide();
        $('.findingtabcontent').show();
        $(document).find('.top-nav2-menu li').removeClass('tabactive');
        $('#findingtab').addClass('tabactive');
        $('#reviewtab').removeClass('tabactivelast');
        document.getElementById('frame1').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
    });
    $('#streetviewtab').click(function() {
        $(document).find('.tabcontent').hide();
        $('.streetviewtabcontent').show();
        $(document).find('.top-nav2-menu li').removeClass('tabactive');
        $('#streetviewtab').addClass('tabactive');
        $('#reviewtab').removeClass('tabactivelast');
        document.getElementById('frame2').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
    });
    $('#videotab').click(function() {
        $(document).find('.tabcontent').hide();
        $('.videotabcontent').show();
        $(document).find('.top-nav2-menu li').removeClass('tabactive');
        $('#videotab').addClass('tabactive');
        $('#reviewtab').removeClass('tabactivelast');
    });
    $('#reviewtab').click(function() {
        $(document).find('.tabcontent').hide();
        $('.reviewtabcontent').show();
        $(document).find('.top-nav2-menu li').removeClass('tabactive');
        $('#reviewtab').addClass('tabactivelast');
    });
});
```

Comment: The code is already adding a "tabactive" class ...

Comment: `$(window).ready(function() {` what's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a pain ...

- `$(window).ready(function() {` should be `$(function() {` 
  which is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`
- In your HTML assign a class `class="tab"` to all your `id="***tab"` elements
- Cache your elements collections `$('.tabcontent')` and `$('.top-nav2-menu li')`
- use the `$(this)` selector

**Than this is all you need:**

```
$(function(){  // DOM is now ready

    // Cache your selectors
    var $tabCont  = $(".tabcontent"),
        $topNavLi = $(".top-nav-menu li"),
        $tabRev   = $('#reviewtab');

    $('.tab').click(function() {

        var myId = this.id;

        if(myId=="findingtab"){
             $('#frame1')[0].contentDocument.location.reload(true);
        }
        if(myId=="streetviewtab"){
             $('#frame2')[0].contentDocument.location.reload(true);
        }        

        $tabCont.hide();
        $("."+ myId +"content").show();

        $(this).addClass('tabactive').siblings().removeClass('tabactive');

        $tabRev.removeClass('tabactivelast');
        if(myId=="reviewtab"){
           $(this).addClass('tabactivelast');
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like:

```
function deactivateAllTabs(){
   $('#infotab, #findingtab, #streetviewtab, #videotab, #reviewtab').removeClass('tabactive');
}
```

Then, prior to adding your `tabactive` class you'd call this method:

So, for example, instead of:

```
$('#infotab').addClass('tabactive');
```

do this:

```
deactivateAllTabs();
$('#infotab').addClass('tabactive');
```

*repeate this for all your click handlerss*

This way, the active tab will always have a `tabactive` class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your DOM structure, since you didn't post it, but I'm assuming that every tab has an identical class, "tabcontent", from what you've posted. If so, you could do something like this inside your function:

```
$('.tabcontent').removeClass('.tabactive'); // removes class from all tabs
$('#sometab').addClass('.tabactive');       // adds class to specific tab
```

Then you could show or hide using just some CSS, like this:

```
.tabcontent { display: none;  }
.tabactive  { display: block; }
```

IMHO you'd also be better off using a single function for all of your tabs so they get the same treatment. Easier to maintain. e.g. Give each tab bar item that you click on to see the tab a data attribute with the id of the div you want to display, and you could expand on something like this (untested but hopefully you get the gist):

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.tabcontent').removeClass('.tabactive');
    $($(this).data('tabcontent')).addClass('.tabactive');
});
```